# How to have different project structures for different git branches in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git

When developing software using the 'git flow' (https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) model, new 'features' are based off a develop branch and when finished, merged back into the 'develop' branch. This means that often, we would be working on multiple features, and thus switching back and forth between multiple feature branches, at a time.

Regarding switching back and forth between different feature branches in Xcode, I keep finding myself re-adjusting the Xcode targets whenever I switch branches: when adding new functionality to a target library whose source files don't exist in the other branch, these files (rightfully so) turn 'red' (meaning they can't be found) when switching to that other branch.

In Xcode 10.0, is there a way I can have different project structures (targets, source files, ...) for each different git branch?

Comment: I don’t know Xcode well enough to verify this, but I would assume you could just add a single commit to each branch that customizes the `.xcodeproj` file to only reference modules that exist. If `.xcodeproj` is a text file, Git should be smart enough to cleanly merge future changes to it from the main branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was that I had put `*.xcodeproj` inside my `.gitignore` file, so Xcode wasn't able to successfully track changed files.

After I stopped ignoring `*.xcodeproj`, I was able to regain the full functionality with git-Xcode again.